# How can I know when another .apk failed to be installed?

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-broadcast

I write a function which can install another app after I click a button in my own app, when another app is installed successfully, I can know it from a broadcast, but my question is when another app failed to be installed, how can I know that? Maybe a better way can make my app control this failed situation automatically.
Can anybody give me a good suggestion, thanks a lot.